# Bring biblatex reference URL on standalone line

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am trying to bring my biblatex reference URL one line down for it to be alone on his lines.
This is the code and the output:

*Main code:*

```
\documentclass[french, 11pt, biblatex]{article}
\usepacakge[]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{xurl}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

Example of text\fullcite{Pericles}

\newpage
\printbibliography
```

*bib.bib code:*

```
@ARTICLE{Pericles,
  title     = "Périclès",
  author  = "Contributeurs de, Wikipédia",
  journal   = "Wikipédia",
  year      = "7 juillet 2012"                 ,
  url       = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P\%C3\%A9ricl\%C3\%A8s#PluVie",
}
```

*The output:*

[image: Output]

The goal is to start the URL at the next line, where it is **alone**.

Comment: `author = "Contributeurs de, Wikipédia",` looks a bit odd, you probably want `author = "{Contributeurs de Wikipédia}",` with an extra pair of curly braces to avoid Biber trying to split the 'corporate name' as a normal name. The `year` field should only contain the year as an integer. If you need a full date, use the `date` field. Replace `year = "7 juillet 2012"` with `date = {2012-07-07},`

Answer (score 1):

I found a way.
In the **\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}** we need to add the parameter **block=ragged**, *just like that:*

```
\usepackage[block=ragged]{biblatex-chicago}
```

*and it output that:*

[image]

What that parameter does is bringing one line down every things that breaks at ends of lines.

**Example:**
*If the title is very long*:
[image]

Comment: `block=ragged,` does not guarantee a line break before URLs (so doesn't guarantee that URLs start in a new line), but it makes it more likely, because it enables a more 'ragged' paragraph layout where line breaks are encouraged over line breaking/hyphenation. Note that `block=ragged,` allows/encourages line breaks in many more places and not just before the URL. Nevertheless the end result is probably often more harmonic when long URLs (or other stuff that is hard to break) are involved than the standard `block=none,`